# Running an AnyCPU application as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS

Tags: .net, windows, 64-bit, executable, compilation

Is there a way to execute a .NET application compiled under AnyCPU as a 32-bit application when running in a 64-bit Windows environment without recompiling as x86?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [corflags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx) with the /32bit+ option.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx) to change the bit without compiling, but you need to modify the application itself to run it.  There is no way to just run the app as 32bit directly.

Alternatively, if you do not want to change the .exe at all, you can make a 32bit compiled application that loads the assembly and starts its entry point.  Since you're loading the assembly into a running 32bit application, it will run as 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Need to change the corflags using corflags.exe as [this blog explains](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/gabrielschenker/archive/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os.aspx).

Comment: Updated the link to a similar blog entry.