# Update Service Reference failed when moving from AnyCPU to x86 in VS2019

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with different projects in C#, including client and host communicating through a WCF service. I had initially build the solution using AnyCPU and everything worked great, I could **Update Service Reference** in the client without problem.

Now, some components in the project required to move everything to x86. I can still build the solution without error but when I click **Update Service Reference** I have an error saying "`The URI prefix is not recognized. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved...`" I double checked and the app.config were identical before and after moving to x86.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in VS2019 ?

**EDITS:**

I forgot to mention, it is a Windows Service using net.pipe. And the error has actually nothing to do with the URI, it is really a x86 vs x64 problem. Actually I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519914/8298327) also talking about a similar issue.
After some troubleshooting, I actually found that the Platform target (in properties) of my WCF library was set to x86. Changing this to AnyCPU solved the problem, even though my Client and Host are still running in x86...  I'd still like to understand what's the deal here... if everything is running x86 anyways, why changing platform target in the library mess up everything?

Comment: did you check IIS AppPool settings? can it be that's still stuck with x64?

Comment: Also posting the example of URI format that is complained about would help to check as well.

Comment: @timur: it is a Windows Service using net.pipe (not IIS).

Comment: @Siva Gopal: I did a bit of troubleshooting and edited the post.

Comment: You can try to use the channel factory to call the wcf service.

Comment: You can also generate proxy classes through svcutil. For how to use svcutil, you can refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631400/adding-wsdl-service-reference-to-vs-fail-because-generated-xsd-file-contains-ill/61725107#61725107

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't really understood the bottom of this issue but instead of having the WCF config in the App.config, I did the configuration programmatically. That seems to have solved the issue, now I can build in x86 no problem.